# How to make hundreds of URLs clickable in Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am migrating documents to Google Docs that contain many URLs. If I hit Enter after each one, the link becomes clickable. But I'm looking for a way to convert all URLs (text starting with http:// or https://) to be clickable.

Is there a macro, add-on or script I could run?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I did some research on using [Google Apps Scripts](https://www.google.com/script/start/) and I came up with this script that works for my needs. I hope it's useful for someone else too.

```js
function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
    .addItem('Make URLs Clickable', 'makeUrlsClickable')
    .addToUi();
}

function makeUrlsClickable() {
  var urlRegex = 'http[s]?:\/\/[^ ]+';
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var urlElement = body.findText(urlRegex);  

  while (urlElement != null) {    
    var urlText = urlElement.getElement().asText();

    var startOffset = urlElement.getStartOffset();
    var endOffset = urlElement.getEndOffsetInclusive();

    urlText.setLinkUrl(startOffset, endOffset, getOnlyUrl(urlText.getText()));

    urlElement = body.findText(urlRegex, urlElement);
  }
}

function getOnlyUrl(text) {
  var startOffset = text.indexOf('http');
  var endOffset = text.indexOf(' ', startOffset);

  if (endOffset === -1) {
    endOffset = text.length;
  }

  return text.substring(startOffset, endOffset);
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Copy and paste links which are already formatted as hyperlinks.

Here's one easy way to do this:

1. Paste your content into a site such as [Convert Plain Text URLs to Link](https://www.smartwebsolutions.org/text-to-url/index.php) (or even a Stack Exchange question or answer draft).
2. Copy the output
3. Paste into your document (don't hold <kbd>shift</kbd>)
4. Remove formatting (this keeps the hyperlink but makes your font match)

This works in both Docs and Sheets, and probably others that I didn't test.

Answer (score -2):

I followed this tutorial: [YouTube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4dgjKuSJN_8)

To summarize it's content: it used *Start* function from *Power Tools* Add-On. As you will see in the video and in your sheet, if you edit the cell having a URL and write one space more after the link and then finalize your cell editing, the link appears as clickable. So the function used makes this 'modification' in a bulk approach. For me worked really well.